# How to shift side navgitation bar from left to right side in vue js

Tags: css, vue.js

I want to shift my side nav from left to right side of the window using vue js.

I tried including following css top: 0 and right: 0 but it is not opening on the right side of the navbar.

Unable to solve this problem. [image]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark sticky-top navbar-top" :class="{ navbaropen: opened}">
  <span class="open-slide">
      <a href="#" @click="opened = !opened">
          <div class="con">
              <div class="bar top" :class="{ topopen: opened}"></div>
              <div class="bar mid" :class="{ midopen: opened}"></div>
              <div class="bar bot" :class="{ botopen: opened}"></div>
          </div>
      </a>
  </span>
  </div>
</nav>
<div id="side-menu" class="side-nav" :class="{ sidenavopen: opened}">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
    <a href="#">Social Media</a>
</div>
.navbaropen{
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 63px;
  margin-right: 250px;
}

.navbar a:hover{
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: #000;
}

.side-nav{
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  opacity: 0.9;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 60px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenavopen{
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  opacity: 0.9;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 60px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

nav{
  transition: margin-left 0.3s;
}
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            listOne: false,
            listTwo: false,
            opened: false
        }
    }
}
```

I want side nav to be opened on the right side while clicking the navigation button.

Comment: hi, please provide running example on codepen https://codepen.io/pen/ or fiddler. so we can help you.

Comment: Just a guess without seeing working example - try to set `left: auto;`

Answer (score 0):

use `left:auto` for `.side-nav` class it will works

```
.side-nav{
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left:auto;
  background-color: #111;
  opacity: 0.9;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 60px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```